# Aggregate rows according to unique identifier

Tags: r, aggregate

Aggregate to rows according to unique identifier?

I have a data frame that has a unique id (syllable) and a duration.
In order to continue my analysis I need to aggregate the data frame by
syllable.

This,

```
syllable   duration
ba         0.20414850
a          0.06804950
na         0.11525535
a          0.09877130
na         0.36774874
ba         0.18228837
ba         0.22232325
```

should look like this:

```
syllable   duration_1    duration_2  duration_3
ba         0.20414850    0.18228837  0.22232325
a          0.06804950    0.09877130
na         0.11525535    0.36774874
```

I tried to the group_by function of dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(syllable) %>%
  summarise(duration = paste(duration, collapse = ","))
```

However, this yields:

```
syllable   duration    
ba         c(0.20414850,0.18228837,0.22232325)
a          c(0.06804950,0.09877130)
na         c(0.11525535,0.36774874)
```

Thank you

Comment: In this case, you need to give R a "time variable" so you can reshape your data to "wide" format. To achieve this, you have to tell R the number of each observation within each group. For example, "this is the first observation of group _ba_, this is the second one, and so on...

Try this:

`library(data.table)
SO <- as.data.table(SO)
SO[, Time_Var := seq(1:.N), by = "syllable"]
SO <- reshape(data = SO, direction = "wide", idvar = "syllable", timevar = "Time_Var")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(syllable) %>%
  mutate(dur = paste0("duration_", row_number())) %>%
  spread(dur, duration) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Output:

```
  syllable duration_1 duration_2 duration_3
1        a  0.0680495  0.0987713         NA
2       ba  0.2041485  0.1822884  0.2223233
3       na  0.1152554  0.3677487         NA
```

I've only added `%>% as.data.frame()` so that it prints all the decimals, otherwise this is not needed.